# What is the next byte after the picture header of an Apple Pro Res 422 encoded video?

Tags: video, header, frame, slice, decoder

I'm trying to understand the format of a piece of the video file in hex listed below. I understand the first chunk. It begins with the 8 bytes of the frame container atom (1000 to 1007), followed by the frame header (148 bytes from 1008 to 109B) and then the picture header (8 bytes from 109C to 10A3). But then I don't understand the next sequence of bytes. I'm following the format of the wiki page listed below, and according to the wiki the next bytes should be the slice header. But the byte 02 at 10A4 does not match up with the slice_hdr_size. Has it already started the codeword scheme? What are these bytes? Thanks!

http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Apple_ProRes

```
0000FF0    00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 09 0A 10
0001004    69 63 70 66  00 94 00 00  61 70 6C 30  07 80 04 38  80 00 01 01 
0001018    01 10 00 03  04 04 05 05  06 07 07 09  04 04 05 06  07 07 09 09 
000102C    05 05 06 07  07 09 09 0A  05 05 06 07  07 09 09 0A  05 06 07 07 
0001040    08 09 0A 0C  06 07 07 08  09 0A 0C 0F  06 07 07 09  0A 0B 0E 11 
0001054    07 07 09 0A  0B 0E 11 15  04 04 05 05  06 07 07 09  04 04 05 06 
0001068    07 07 09 09  05 05 06 07  07 09 09 0A  05 05 06 07  07 09 09 0A 
000107C    05 06 07 07  08 09 0A 0C  06 07 07 08  09 0A 0C 0F  06 07 07 09 
0001090    0A 0B 0E 11  07 07 09 0A  0B 0E 11 15  40 00 09 09  36 03 FC 30

00010A4    02 2E 02 63  02 19 02 11  02 71 02 40  01 D7 02 0A  02 44 02 3B 
00010B8    02 B2 02 CB  02 48 02 5C  02 7E 02 53  02 67 02 35  01 FE 02 70 
00010CC    02 AC 01 CF  02 1C 02 28  02 35 02 B1  02 13 02 40  02 4D 02 62 
00010E0    02 47 02 23  02 2E 02 02  02 7B 02 B5  01 B3 02 12  02 41 02 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice index table consists of 16bit entries - one for each slice - giving the length of the data for each slice. Thus, it permits independent processing of the slices in means of multi-threading.